# How to make two thin lines next to my text? (HTML) (CSS)

Tags: html, css

I have managed to center my text.

But now I would like to have two thin lines on either side of my text as seen on this website:

I have marked the lines in red

[image]

So far I have created a div in html, and then used css.
Here is my html: (I left it empty because the text is separate)

```css
div {
  width: 1000px;
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

And here is what my result looks like:

As you can see, the lines are above the text. However I want those lines to be on either sides of the text.

[image]

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add the HTML for your text too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you paste your text inside that div you get your expected result.

```css
div {
  width: 1000px;
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 1vh 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div>
   <h1>This is your title</h1>
   <p>This is you paragraph</p>

</div>
```

Comment: @coelestium no problem ;) Don't forget to mark this as the answer.

Comment: I have marked your answer as correct. Thank you. However I have to manually set the length of the lines to match the text. Is there a way to set it, so that the lines automatically adjust to the amount of text? What Im trying to say, is that when I put in text and set the "sideline" length to 1000px, the line is too long. Do I have to manually change this to match it or can I automate this?

Comment: @coelestium you can solve this by removing the width and adding `display: inline-block` to the div style.

Answer (score 0):

if you want the lines around the text change the display to display:inline-block;

```css
div {
  display:inline-block;
  border-right: 2px solid gray;
  border-left: 2px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-content: center;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>all my tutorials</div>
```

Comment: Im very sorry, but your solution didnt help now that I have tested it. The correct way was to put my content into the <div></div> tags. But thank you for putting so much effort into your answer!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way is bootstrap. You can use the card component. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/card/

I made a simple demo for you with bootstrap you can see more details of bootstrap here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
  </head>
  <br>
  <body>
   <div class="card mx-auto" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
    <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Card link</a>
    <a href="#" class="card-link">Another link</a>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

    <!-- Option 1: jQuery and Bootstrap Bundle (includes Popper) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Option 2: jQuery, Popper.js, and Bootstrap JS
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: tha so much! thats very helpful!!

Comment: you are welcome :) can you mark the answer as "accepted"?

Comment: im sorry but unfortunately another solution was a lot simpler for me. I just put my content into the <div></div>. Thank you for putting so much effort into your answer though! Im sure your solution is also very elegant!